# How to initialize submodule that is in an AWS lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm running a NodeJS lambda on AWS that uses a submodule. When run locally this code works but in AWS I cannot import the submodule and it seems it's due to the submodule not being initialized. What is the best way to initialize this submodule? I can't seem to find documentation anywhere on this.

Comment: What do you mean by submodule? An NPM package, or a seperate module file? Did you guys check on the files, what all the files which are uploaded next to your entry point file? What is the error message?

Comment: It's using a git submodlue that is checked into the pkg folder. The error is that it can't find the file that should be located in the submodule.